# Cant Display Image from API in Html (Using angular 7)

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular7

**i want to display amages from API in my html page
this is my code and the result
any help!!??**

Answer (score 0):

Keep the image data in a variable

and just write in HTML

<img src="{{varName?.image}}" your image will displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your data in a variable and use attribute data binding to load the image like this:

```html
<img [src]="data.imagePath" alt="image" />
```